# powershell weird output array index

Tags: powershell

I have an array of numbers (larger than the example)

```
$ccheck = ("44729375","74729375")

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $ccheck.Count; $i++ ) {
     cd $env:userprofile\desktop\CURL\
     $ccheck[$i]
     $curlexec ="curl -L ""https://server.net/$ccheck[$i]""";
     $curlexec
}
```

with a for loop I am iterating over an array. When asking for index with `$ccheck[$i]`  I am getting the first index which is `44729375`. But from `$curlexec` variable I am getting the whole array and I just want the i index.

So I am getting this as as output  `https://server.net/44729375 74729375` from the variable `$curlexec`. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [`Get-Help 'about_Quoting_Rules'`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).

Use either *sub-expression syntax*

```
 $curlexec ="curl -L ""https://server.net/$($ccheck[$i])""";
 ##### note the change                    $(           )
```

or an *auxiliary variable*

```
 $ccheckaux = $ccheck[$i]
 $curlexec ="curl -L ""https://server.net/$ccheckaux""";
```